# pytransitions/transitions: Is there any better way to store the history of visited state?

Tags: python, transition, pytransitions

I recently spotted a lightweight, object-oriented state machine implementation in Python called transitions (https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions). So I'm trying to play a bit with these state machines and especially with the HierarchicalGraphMachine. One the the nice features that I'd like to have is to store the history of the visited states even when the machine does not move (stays in the same state).

And from what I see from the examples, we actually could not do it in a easy way because the `before_state_change` and `after_state_change` was NOT called when the machine's state is unchanged. So we cannot extend our history in this case. In order to fix that, I end up by creating a trigger_wrapper function:

```
def trigger_wrapper(self, trigger_name):
        
        previous_state = self.state

        result = None
        try:
            result = self.trigger(trigger_name)
        except AttributeError as attribute_err:
            print('Invalid trigger name: {}'.format(attribute_err))
        except MachineError as machine_err:
            print('Valid trigger name but not reachable: {}'.format(machine_err))
        except Exception as err:
            print('Cannot make transition with unknown error: {}'.format(err))
        
        if result is False:
            print('Trigger name reachable but condition(s) was not fulfilled')
            ....

        current_state = self.state

        # update history
        ..... 

        return result
```

Then, we call trigger_wrapper instead of trigger:

```
before: machine.trigger('drink')
now:    machine.trigger_wrapper('drink').
```

In addition to that, by setting `ignore_invalid_triggers = False` when initialize the `Machine` and use this `trigger_wrapper` function, we could now know the reason why the machine cannot make a move by caching the exceptions.

Is there any better solution for keep tracking the visited state? An another approach I think is to overwrite trigger function but it seems complicated due to the `NestedState`.

**Edit 1** (follow to the suggestion by @aleneum)

Thank you for your response together with an interesting example !!!

Follow the example that using the `finalize_event`. It goes well, but this callback function seems do not enough to catch the following cases (I added 2 extra lines in the code):

```
... same setup as before
m.go()
m.internal()
m.reflexive()
m.condition()
m.go()    # MachineError: "Can't trigger event go from state B!"
m.goo()   # AttributeError: Do not know event named 'goo'.

>>> Expected: ['go', 'internal', 'reflexive', 'condition', 'go', 'goo'] 
>>> Expected: ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

In other words, is there another callback that we could catch the exceptions caused by calling `invalid trigger` (goo in the example) or caused by `valid trigger but not reachable from the current state` (call go() from state B) ?

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already mentioned, `before_state_change` and `after_state_change` are only called when a transition takes place. This does not necessarily mean a state change though as internal and reflexive transitions also trigger these callbacks:

```py
from transitions import Machine


def test():
    print("triggered")


m = Machine(states=['A', 'B'], transitions=[
    ['go', 'A', 'B'],
    dict(trigger='internal', source='B', dest=None),
    dict(trigger='reflexive', source='B', dest='='),
    dict(trigger='condition', source='B', dest='A', conditions=lambda: False)
], after_state_change=test, initial='A')


m.go()  # >>>  triggered
m.internal()  # >>> triggered
m.reflexive()  # >>> triggered
m.condition()  # no output
```

The only event that does NOT trigger the `after_state_change` here is `m.condition` since the transition was halted by the (unfulfilled) condition.

So, when your goal is to track actually conducted transitions, `after_state_change` is the right spot. If you want to log every trigger/event, you can do this via `finalize_event`:

> 'machine.finalize_event'  - callbacks will be executed even if no transition took place or an exception has been raised

```py
from transitions import Machine


event_log = []
state_log = []


def log_trigger(event_data):
    event_log.append(event_data.event.name)
    state_log.append(event_data.state)


m = Machine(states=['A', 'B'], transitions=[
    ['go', 'A', 'B'],
    dict(trigger='internal', source='B', dest=None),
    dict(trigger='reflexive', source='B', dest='='),
    dict(trigger='condition', source='B', dest='A', conditions=lambda event_data: False)
], finalize_event=log_trigger, initial='A', send_event=True)


m.go()
m.internal()
m.reflexive()
m.condition()

print(event_log)  # >>> ['go', 'internal', 'reflexive', 'condition']
print([state.name for state in state_log])  # >>> ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

Callbacks passed to `finalize_event` will always be called, even if the transition raised an exception. By setting `send_event=True`, all callbacks will receive an `EvenData` object which contains event, state and transition information as well as an error object if something went wrong. This is way I have to change the condition lambda expression. When `send_event=True`, ALL callbacks need to be able to process the `EventData` object.

More information about `finalize_event` and the callback execution order can be found in [this section](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#callback-execution-order) of the documentation.

#### How to log invalid events too?

`finalize_event` is only called for valid events which means the event must exist and must also be valid on the current source state. If ALL events should be processed, `Machine` needs to be extended:

```
from transitions import Machine

log = []


class LogMachine(Machine):

    def _get_trigger(self, model, trigger_name, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super(LogMachine, self)._get_trigger(model, trigger_name, *args, **kwargs)
        log.append((trigger_name, model.state))
        return res

# ...
m = LogMachine(states=..., ignore_invalid_triggers=True)
assert m.trigger("go")  # valid
assert not m.trigger("go")  # invalid
assert not m.trigger("gooo")  # invalid
print(log)  # >>> [('go', 'B'), ('go', 'B'), ('gooo', 'B')]
```

Every model is decorated with a `trigger` method which is a partial of `Machine._get_trigger` with assigned `model` parameter. `Model.trigger` can be used to trigger events by name and also to process non-existent events. You also need to pass `ignore_invalid_triggers=True` to not raise `MachineError` when an event is invalid.

However, if all events should be logged, it is probably more feasible/maintainable to split logging from `Machine` and handle logging where events are processed, e.g.:

```py
m = Machine(..., ignore_invalid_triggers=True)
# ...
def on_event(event_name):
   logging.debug(f"Received event {event_name}")  # or log_event.append(event_name)
   m.trigger(event_name)
   logging.debug(f"Machine state is {m.state}")  # or log_state.append(m.state)
```

Comment: @nghia: You can ignore invalid triggers with `ignore_invalid_triggers=True`. `finalize_event` however, will only be called for valid events. If you want a Machine to log ALL events, you need to extend  `Machine` and make use of `Model.trigger` to call events by name.

Comment: Hi @aleneum, thank you very much. Overwrite "_get_trigger" is what I need.